# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME Shell is keep crashing

Tags: 18.04, crash, gnome-shell, logout

I installed ubuntu 18.04 today in my laptop lenovo yoga 500. and when i try to change font in gonome tweak tool gnome shell is crashed and logged me out immediately. same problem with visual studio code. when I try to open a folder in visual studio code it logged me out. and when I ran a tkniter program in python.

it first started when I ran the first script

from [here](https://gist.github.com/MaxySpark/72e2b35fff0056f82ebc636b47b159ec)  (it is a bash script i wrote to install some software quickly in fresh installation) 
I don't know why this is happening please help.

I other questions i read nvidia driver causes this problem. But i installed, uninstalled, reinstalled nvidia driver but it didn't help.

Comment: didn't find any solution. ...

Comment: installed kde plasma desktop environment. now working fine with plasma

Comment: I'm having similar problem with Clevo N240GU.

Comment: try this
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')`


 AND 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs:i386`